# Unmarshalling implemented interface structs in Go

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I am trying to read some JSON and unmarshal it into a data structure, defined below.

```
type TaskGroup struct {
    GroupName  string             `json:"groupName"`
    ModuleType modules.ModuleType `json:"module"`
    Project    string             `json:"project"`
    Tasks      map[string]*Task   `json:"tasks"`
}


type Task struct {
    Price       float64         `json:"price"`
    TaskOpts    modules.Module  `json:"opts"`
}
```

where Module is:

```
type Module interface {
    Run(ctx context.Context)
}
```

which are implemented by:

```
type ModuleA struct {
    TaskType  modules.ModuleType
    ProductID string
}
type ModuleB struct {
    TaskType modules.ModuleType
    CMID     string
}
```

So when I try to unmarshal JSON from a file, I get the following error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Task.tasks.opts of type modules.Module
```

Is this possible? Not sure if this is an error elsewhere or it's because I'm trying to unmarshal into an interface

Comment: I second that. I have exactly the same question, but all solutions that I was able to find seem to be irrelevant. Even if I have method that can convert `[]byte` to implementation of `Module` it can not be used, because It's impossible to implement `UnmarshalJSON` for the `Module` as it's an interface. Implementing `UnmarshalJSON`  for the whole `TaskGroup` makes no sense, because it will require to parse all fields.